# Compact spaces in $l_p$ with $(1\leq p<+\infty)$

Tags: compactness, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

*Let be $K \subset l_p$ closed set, with $(1\leq p<+\infty)$. Prove that $K$ is compact if and only if:*

- *$\forall n\geq1:\sup\{|x_n| : x=\{x_n\}_{n\geq1}\}<+\infty$*
- *$\lim_{m\rightarrow +\infty} \sup\{\sum_{n\geq m} |x_n|^p : x=\{x_n\}_{n\geq 1} \in K\}=0$*

Here's what I was able to prove: I supposed $K$ compact and so, for the characterization of compact sets in a Banach space, $K$ must be bounded and closed. So, because $K$ is bounded is immediate that: $\sup\{|x_n| : x=\{x_n\}_{n\geq1}\}<+\infty$.
I don't know how to prove the second point and I don't know to prove the viceversa, I guess I would have to prove that $K$ is bounded, and that comes easy from the first point, but how do I manage to create a collection of sets $M_\xi$ such that:

$$\forall \xi >0 \ \ \exists M_\xi \ subspace, \ dim(M_\xi)<+\infty \ : \ d(K, M_\xi) < \xi$$

A note: I define $lp$ as such:
$$l_p=\{x=\{x_n\}_{n \geq 1} | \sum_{n \geq 1}|x_n|^p <+\infty\}$$

Comment: Hint: $\ell_{p}$ is a metric space with the metric $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|_{p}$. In metric spaces, compactness and sequential compactness (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequentially_compact_space)) are equivalent.

Comment: Your first condition is something that is true for all $x \in \ell_p$, practically by definition. It has nothing to do with $K$. Did you copy it correctly? And on the 2nd condition, shouldn't that be the limit as $m \to +\infty$?

Comment: I corrected the first and second statement, I left out the part where it says "$\forall n \geq1 $" because to me didn't make much sense